# Change volume by one instead of two

Tags: windows-8.1, audio

When you turn the volume up or down in Windows using a keyboard/mouse shortcut, it increases by two instead of one. Is it possible to set this to one?

Answer (score 0):

You may use third-party software like [Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html).

The sound can be adjusted by scrolling the mousewheel while holding the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key down.

Comment: You are recommending 3rd party software.

Comment: @vembutech As long as a recommendation helps resolve the problem, there isn't anything wrong with recommending 3rd party software. If the recommendation is spam or self-promotion then it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the laptop/desktop firmware. My Acer laptop changes in steps of 2 when I use the [Fn+VolUp] or [Fn+VolDown] keyboard keys. But if I manually adjust the volume, I can set it in steps of 1. My audio is the "RealTek HD Audio" if that is important.

If your volume ranges from a minimum of 0 to a maximum of 100 (as mine does), then the fine control of stepping by 1 may make changing the volume overly-tedious while giving almost no perceptible change in output. In this case, stepping by 2 seems to me to be the sweet-spot, making perceptible volume changes quickly but also controllable.

EDIT

The following 3rd party tool was recommended in another forum and may work for you: http://sourceforge.net/projects/volstep/. As pointed out in that download, the default step size is 2% or 4% of the maximum volume range (ie. a step size of 2 if the maximum is 100). While this tool will almost certainly work for you, you need to know that it may disable the OSD (on-screen display) of the volume as you tap the multimedia keys.