# Increase and decrease volume by 1 instead of 2

Tags: windows-10, audio, fn-key

So when i use FN+volume_up my volume goes from 0 to 2. Im want to change it so it always goes up by 1. I know about this has already been asked [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/questions/891725/change-volume-by-one-instead-of-two) but 
this uses 3rd party software.
Is it possible without that?

im using the Dell optiplex E7270

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What laptop do you have? It will depend on the drivers your pc is using

Comment: @marijnr Dell Latitude E7270

Comment: can you edit the question instead of commenting it?